# Store vsdx files in a list to iterate through and unzip

Tags: python

**EDIT: Using match's suggestion below here's my working code:**

```py
def buildReport():
    global dirName #default dir or user selected dir
    files=list(Path(dirName).glob('*.vsdx'))
    print(files)
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(dir=defaultInitDir) as tempdir:
        for index, file in enumerate(files):
            with ZipFile(files[index]) as vsdx:
                vsdx.extractall(tempdir)
            for path in Path(tempdir).iterdir(): #Test to determine if tempdir was created
                print(path)
```

**With the following output:**

```
[WindowsPath('C:/python/WPT-ReportBuilder/Working/vsdx/Test.vsdx'),
WindowsPath('C:/python/WPT-ReportBuilder/Working/vsdx/Test2.vsdx')]
C:\python\WPT-ReportBuilder\Working\tmpxsungorv\docProps
C:\python\WPT-ReportBuilder\Working\tmpxsungorv\visio
C:\python\WPT-ReportBuilder\Working\tmpxsungorv\[Content_Types].xml
C:\python\WPT-ReportBuilder\Working\tmpxsungorv\_rels
C:\python\WPT-ReportBuilder\Working\tmpxsungorv\docProps
C:\python\WPT-ReportBuilder\Working\tmpxsungorv\visio
C:\python\WPT-ReportBuilder\Working\tmpxsungorv\[Content_Types].xml
C:\python\WPT-ReportBuilder\Working\tmpxsungorv\_rels
```

I had to add the index to the for loop because I kept getting a TypeError

**ORIGINAL:**

I'm trying to store the paths of several .vsdx files located in a specific directory (that defaults to a directory relative to the script I'm running, or is user selectable through tkinter's askdirectory command).

Once they're stored in a list, I'm going to iterate through each file and do the following things:

- Unzip the file into a temporary folder
- Parse through some of the xml files included for data
- Build an excel report where each file has its own sheet with the data I've pulled from the .vsdx file

I've got a program that similarly grabs the xml data and have the GUI operational. I'm pretty confident that part will work, but I can't get the files stored in a list properly to be able to loop through it.

Here's what I've got so far:

```py
def buildReport():
    global dirName #default dir or user selected dir
    files_Path=list(Path(dirName).glob('*.vsdx'))
    print(files_Path)
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(dir=defaultInitDir) as tempdir:
        files_Path[0].extractall(tempdir)
        for path in Path(tempdir).iterdir(): #Test to determine if tempdir was created
            print(path)
```

Here's my output:

```
[WindowsPath('C:/python/WPT-ReportBuilder/Working/vsdx/Test.vsdx')]
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\python\WPT-ReportBuilder\Working\script1.py", line 47, in buildReport
    files_Path[0].extractall(tempdir)
AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'extractall'
```

I've tried converting the path to a string, using os instead of pathlib, and several other things, but just can get it to work how I think it should.

I know it's going to be something simple, but I'm very new to python and have been beating my head against this for a couple of days and can't get anywhere. Please help and TYIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you probably want to use [`ZipFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) to first load a zip archive, then call the `extractall` method on that instance. Something like:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile(files_Path[0]) as zf:
    zf.extractall(tempdir)
```